# What is this tree? Forgot to record what I planted

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees

I planted this tree three years ago and forget to record what type it was. The grower's tag has apparently fallen off some time ago.

It is 95% certain to be a fruit tree, but could be a nut. Likeliest candidates are a cherry or an apple, but could be something like a plum or apricot/peach/nectarine.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Alternatively, I could wait another two years until it produces mystery fruit![image]

Comment: Send a pic of the entire tree, please.  Is there a tree ring as it is planted in the lawn?  Too much nitrogen (lawn fertilizer) will inhibit flowering and promote vegetative growth...and disease/insects.

Comment: Stormy has a good point. After three years you should have seen some flowers (maybe you did), and possibly some fruits. Apricots are difficult plants, and as you see, your plant is not so healthy (see the dead buds). She tends to flower too early, but on the same time she hates cold.

Comment: And one small trick for next time. Do a photo of the tags, and store in a garden folder. So you will not loose such information, and google/apple will take care to remember it for you.

Comment: @stormy Oops, meant to have the full tree in there. Added it.

Comment: @Giacomo Yea, she's definitely not doing well, but she survived multiple (mini) floods! To be honest, I'm surprised she lived. She was planted in a poor location it turns out in retrospect, and four other trees near her - including a cherry on either side of her - were killed from the water which sat an inch or two up their trunks for ten days or so on more than one occasion. Under those circumstances, I think she's a fine survivor! I'll relocate her 8" higher elevation up the slope in the next few weeks.

Comment: @stormy No lawn fertalizer is used. In fact, no fertalizer at all has been used on her ever (which will be remedied when I relocate her). I think any weakness is primarily from the floods she encountered last year and her having just broken dormancy a month ago.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is *Prunus armeniaca*, so the apricot.

Why? The red shots and red young leaves, the form of leaves (rolled) and the bright colour.  Plum (as *Prunus domestica*): I see red shots only on base of the trees, the leaves are darker, and I don't remember in such form (I think the leaves are more straight and with shorter stalks).

Comment: Thank you! If it gets any fruit this year (this would be the first year) I'll post again and let everyone know what it was. It might not fruit until next year, though.

Comment: Knowing the likeliest candidate helps me know what additional trees I need to get, and which trees I can safely skip for another year. Thanks again; glad I didn't buy a bunch of apricot trees!

Comment: Never grown an apricot, but I would vote against peach/nectarine.

Comment: @winwaed: I totally agree for my case, but I think it is very climate dependant. Apricot trees are the "difficult" ones.

Comment: I meant "vote against" as in deciding from the photo: It didn't look like a peach. Peaches grow quite well here in Texas (we planted one at the new house last year and had peach&nectarine at our previous house)